# hdd crashed 'magnetic surface degradation'

Tags: hard-drive

my computer hdd just died, no odd sounds before or after, even when connecting via usb, test shows 'no bootable device - please insert boot disk) i'm told 'magnetic surface degradation' has occurred - advanced recovery needed. is there no other way/tips than professional recovery, since that will not restore the applications / programmes, (which is more important) just the data they create?.

thanks

Comment: This type of failure cannot be resolved with equipment you have access to

Comment: Who said your disk has 'magnetic surface degradation' and why do you trust them ?   Based on the limited information you have provided it would seem orders of magnitude more likely there is a problem with the hard drive controller.

Answer (score 0):

try hard disk re-generator and a recovery tool. strip the pc, check the cabling is all secure, psu isn't clogged with dust and dirt (don't open your psu as it's dangerous if you don't know what you are doing). you may not have a working hard disk for long if regenerator works and a recovery tool works but at least you can get data off it. good luck.

Edit:
the reason for stripping the pc and checking for damaged or loose cabling is to ensure there isn't a root cause from that which would effect the hdd if it is recovered or a replaced.

Answer (score -1):

It almost sounds as if someone has sabotaged your system. Usually for the magnetic surface to degrade to the point you describe, a device similar to a magnetic tape eraser has to be held close to the source, in your case the hard drive. I'm afraid you will more than likely have to buy a new hard drive. I could be wrong. I would advise contacting your hard drive manufacturer and asking them if this could have occurred. They might be interested in getting the hard drive back to see what went wrong, and may give you a new drive in return. You will still need your system recovery disc and start anew. Sorry, but this all the knowledge I have concerning this sort of situation. It is the first time I've heard it happening to a computer hard drive.